# AngularJS $httpBackend verify no interactions

Tags: angularjs

I'm looking for a way to evaluate `$httpBackend` to see if there are any interactions. I want to make sure it has never been called at this point in my test case. I've checked the documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend and haven't found the answer.

Class using $http

```
class HomeService {
  /*@ngInject*/
  constructor ($http, $log) {
    this.http = $http;
    this.log = $log;
  }

  submit(keycode) {
    this.log.log("submitting key code: " + keycode);
    if (keycode === "") {
      return false;
    }
    this.http.post(`/api/keycode/${keycode}`).then ( (response) => {
      this.log.log(response);
      return true;
    });
  }
}

export default HomeService;
```

test case so far.

```
import HomeService from './home.service';

describe('HomeService', () => {
  let homeService, $httpBackend;

  beforeEach(inject(($injector) => {
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
   $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
   $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
 });

  describe('submit', () => {

    it('submit empty keycode', () => {
      homeService = new HomeService($httpBackend, console);
      let value = homeService.submit("");
      expect(value).to.be.false;
      //valid no interactions with $httpBackend here!
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: HomeService should be injected with $http, not $httpBackend.

Answer (score 0):

Even though

```
  afterEach(function() {
   $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
   $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
 });
```

may be enough to throw on unwanted requests, to tie an error to specific spec use:

```
expect($httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation).not.toThrow();
```